# How would I go about turning the characters in a word that a user inputs into an array that contains the letters in the word?

Tags: java, initialization

I am trying to code a hangman game in java. Using JOptionPane to ask the user for a word, how would I go about turning the characters in a word that a user inputs into an array that contains the letters in the word?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr = "foo".split("")
```

Would return the array:

```
[ "f", "o", "o" ]
```

Alternatively, this could be done with a for loop as such:

```
String s = "bar";
String[] arr = new String[s.length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = s.substring(i, i + 1);
}
```

returning the output:

```
[ "b", "a", "r" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the String class is a little bit like a decorated array (the characters are internally stored in an array). So your best bet honestly is just to use String or StringBuilder

But if it needs to be a char[], you can create your array using

```
char[] entries = new char[26];
entriesLength = 0;
```

And then when you have another guess

```
entries[entriesLength++] = newGuess;
```